# Sql insert into table using Loop

Tags: sql, while-loop

I have this dataSet :

[image]

which i get after running this query :

```
SELECT  
MachineEquioement.NumMachine
,Equipements.Nom as 'Equipement'
,MachineEquioement.QTE
FROM MachineEquioement
inner join Equipements on Equipements.NumEquipement = MachineEquioement.NumEquipement
order by NumMachine
```

The result i want to have is as below :

```
NumMachine || Equipement
1          || Moteur N° 1
1          || Accouplement avec caoutchouc N° 1
1          || Accouplement avec caoutchouc N° 2
1          || Palier P216 N° 1
1          || Palier P216 N° 2
```

Does anyone has a good idea for it? Is it possible?

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using/ As for your question, what does this have to do with While Loops? Why do you *want* to use a While Loop in SQL, which is a set based language?

Comment: What is the maximum value that `QTE` could have too?

Comment: i need to loop on the QTE column value for each row to have the result i want

Comment: If you are writing a loop in SQL, you are very likely doing it wrong. There are very few times you should be using them in SQL. There are, however, set based methods but their implementation is RDBMS specific, and we don't know what one you are using.

Comment: QTE does not have a maximum value it can be any posetive value

Comment: You don't need a while loop. Whatever the backend is, in most of the SQL databases you can do this joining with a tally table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you are trying to achieve ?

```
;WITH  cte
                        as (  select MachineEquioement.NumMachine,Equipements.Nom ,QTE
                        
                           FROM MachineEquioement
                            INNER join Equipements on Equipements.NumEquipement = MachineEquioement.NumEquipement
                            WHERE  QTE >0
                            union all
                            select  MachineEquioement.NumMachine,Equipements.Nom ,QTE -1 
                              from     cte
                            WHERE  QTE >1
                            
                            ) 

SELECT  
NumMachine
,Nom as 'Equipement'
,QTE
FROM cte
order by NumMachine option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: 2 notes: 1. `;` is a statement **terminator**; it goes at the end of *all* your statements not the start of the statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. 2. As the value of `QTE` grows, the performance here will get significantly worse.

Comment: agree. but if he requires to generate as many rows as QTE this is an easy option

Comment: is there any error or different output ? if you can share sample script with data it will be better to share exact query for desired output

Comment: agree. but if he/she requires to generate as many rows as QTE this is an easy option. I guess this would be better :)